Generating equivalent normal and lognormal distributions
Letting $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma)$ and $Y = e^X \sim LN(\mu, \sigma)$, I want to generate the same distribution using R or some other program. My understanding is that the parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$ should be the same.
However, the two probability density plots don't line up.
# parameters
mX <- 1 # muX
sX <- 1 # sigmaX

# quantiles
x <- qnorm(seq(.001, .999, length = 1000), mX, sX)
y <- qlnorm(seq(.001, .999, length = 1000), mX, sX)

# prob. density
pX <- dnorm(x, mX, sX)
pY <- dlnorm(y, mX, sX)

# plot
plot.new()
plot.window(c(-5, 5), c(0, .8))
lines(x, pX, col = 1)
lines(log(y), pY, col = 2)
legend("topright", lty = 1, col = 1:2, legend = c("X", "Y"))
axis(1)
axis(2)
box()


What am I doing wrong? I know that
$$
E[Y] = e^{\mu + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2}
$$
and
$$
Var[Y] = e^{2\mu + \sigma^2}(e^{\sigma^2} - 1)
$$
but I don't think this is what should be used for the parameters of the lognormal distribution in qlnorm. (And equivalent functions in other programs.)

The Jacobian is missing when plotting dlnorm.

Oh yes, thanks @Xi'an.
Given cdf $F$, the normal pdf is
$$
\frac{dF_X(x)}{dx}
$$
and the lognormal pdf is
$$
\frac{dF_Y(y)}{dy}
$$
To get the same plot I need
$$
\frac{dF_Y(y)}{dx} = \frac{dF_Y(y)}{dy} \frac{dy}{dx}
$$
where
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = e^x = y
$$
Therefore,
plot.new()
plot.window(c(-5, 5), c(0, .8))
lines(x, pX, col = 1)
lines(log(y), pY * y, col = 2)
legend("topright", lty = 1, col = 1:2, legend = c("X", "Y"))
axis(1)
axis(2)
box()


And I get what I'm looking for. Thanks a lot.
